# Face becomes stretched when using Inset tool

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, faces, selection-tools, select

I have a face:
[image]

When I press "I" key for insetting it, it gets stretched and looks like this:
[image]

Comment: you probably need to correct the left part manually with some scale and move

Comment: An important question is **why** do you want to inset. Do you then want to extrude? What is the shape you want to extrude? Or maybe you want to create *holding edges* for subdivision?

Comment: I wanted to extrude upwards

Comment: Then the shape you wanted to extrude probably should be somehow related to the rest of the shape: e.g. you probably don't want two super sharp edges created in your answer. Maybe you also want a roughly equal margin to the edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the fact, press E and then Right Click
Now scale it down. Simple!
[image]